# Block async method manually

Tags: c#, async-await, blocking

My knowledge of how `async/await` methods are run and on what thread is a little hazy.  I would like to block a method until an event is fired.  To do this I tried using the `ManualResetEvent` however this blocks every call to the async method until the last `waitHandle.Set( )` is called at which point all `async` methods complete (or so it seems).

I need a way to block `async` calls individually as I'm trying to convert the event based asynchronous approach to a `Task` based `async/await` one.

How can/should I go about it?

**Update:**

Based on the information provided by Stephen and Noseratio, I have now changed my asynchronous methods to something a long the lines of this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<CustomerNoteInfo>> LoadClientNotesAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _session.InvokeOperationAsync((client) =>
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IEnumerable<CustomerNoteInfo>>( );
            client.GetCustomerNotesCompleted += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Error != null) tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
                else tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result);
            };

            client.GetCustomerNotesAsync(id);
            return tcs.Task;
        }).Unwrap( );
    }
```

I'm sure this is going to look ugly to everyone who has ever done any async/await Task based programming, but am I on the right track for this?  It seems to have fixed the problem I was having with the manual reset event and I can now run this method multiple times asynchronously. :)

Comment: How would I use `Task.Factory.FromAsync` with the asynchronous methods event pairs generated by an Add Service Reference in a portable class library?

As these methods do not return `IAsyncResult` or the like.

Comment: If you have events, use `TaskCompletionSource`. [How to: Wrap EAP Patterns in a Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622454(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My knowledge of how async/await methods are run and on what thread is a little hazy.

I recommend you start with my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), which covers the keywords and how they determine which thread to use.

> I'm trying to convert the event based asynchronous approach to a Task based async/await one.

The [MSDN documentation on this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#EAP) is quite good.

You do not need to block an `async` method; just create a TAP (Task-based) wrapper for the EAP (method/event pair). Then you can just call your TAP method and `await` the returned task.